# How to put viewControllers into loop array?

Tags: ios, arrays, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, swift5

I am trying to use customized tab viewController, in which the user can add/re-arrange them the way he/she likes. in the following code I only need to return the array count and display the array items, I managed to do it by a number of the array, but when using it as a single array code, it displays only one view controller!!

here is the code:

```
class ContainerController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let selectedViewControllers = [Home(),Index(),Favourite(),Library()]
        let selectedViewControllersProperties = ["Home","Index","Favourite","Library"]

        viewControllers = [createController(title: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[0])".localized, imageName: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[0])", vc: selectedViewControllers[0]),
        createController(title: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[1])", imageName: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[1])", vc: selectedViewControllers[1]),
        createController(title: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[2])", imageName: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[2])", vc: selectedViewControllers[2]),
        createController(title: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[3])", imageName: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[3])", vc: selectedViewControllers[3]),]
    }

    // MARK: - Handlers
    func createController(title: String, imageName: String, vc: UIViewController) -> UINavigationController{

        let recentVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        recentVC.tabBarItem.title = title
        recentVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        return recentVC
    }
}
```

When trying to use this array instead, it shows only ONE viewController:

```
let tabCount = selectedViewControllersProperties.count - 1

for i in 0...tabCount {
      viewControllers = [createController(title: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[i])".localized, imageName: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[i])", vc: selectedViewControllers[i])]
}
```

What I did wrong here, please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of the for loop, you are just setting a new array (with only one item) to `viewControllers`, which is why `viewControllers` will only have one item in the end as well.

You need to `append` the new VCs to the array, instead of using `=`:

```
let tabCount = selectedViewControllersProperties.count

// ..< is safer
var viewControllers = [] // you don't seem to have declared this beforehand.
for i in 0..<tabCount {
     viewControllers.append(createController(title: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[i])".localized, imageName: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[i])", vc: selectedViewControllers[i]))
}
```

You can also do this with `map`:

```
viewControllers = (0..<tabCount).map {
    createController(title: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[$0])".localized, imageName: "\(selectedViewControllersProperties[$0])", vc: selectedViewControllers[$0])
}
```

Comment: But the first append didn't

Comment: @HussamDabaan You probably declared the array but haven't show it then. Delete the word `var` and it should work.

Comment: Error: Value of type '[UIViewController]?' has no member 'append'

Comment: @HussamDabaan Add a question mark `?` before the `.append`.